# Fibonacci Riddle almost right in need of a quick fix and an easy solve

Tags: java, fibonacci

Help I have a puzzle that needs solved!
I made a Fibonacci series but I forgot to include the 0
Who can help me solve this riddle?
If the input is five in the sequence the output should be 0,1,1,2,3
What should I change to clean up the code and get the desired result without completely starting from scratch?

```
//Class Assignment 9 little Fibonacci series based on what input
//the user provides
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LittleFibonacci {

    int number;// This declares an int variable
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //itnu is the new object
        LittleFibonacci itnu = new LittleFibonacci ();
        itnu.GetNumberInput();
     }

    public void GetNumberInput()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number and that number will be a" +
                " \nrepresentitive of the length of a sequence in the Fibonocci series.");
        number = input.nextInt();
        int f1, f2=0, f3=1;

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= number ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(" "+f3+" ");
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            f3 = f1 + f2;
        }    
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Change your code to output `0` before the start of your `for` loop, and shorten the number of loop iterations by `1` (by removing one character from the loop termination value).

Comment: Note that it's Fibonacci, not Fibonocci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
 System.out.print(" "+f2+" ");
```

before the for loop. Change the for loop terminating condition to <.

I guess to be really completist we should also check that the user does not enter 0 (or a negative number) and not even print f2 in that case.

This may seem slightly "unclean" but the fibonacci sequence has two starting numbers, they are special and need special treatment.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to give general instructions instead of writing the code, so the poster could just figure it out and learn something in the process?

Comment: The two starting numbers do not need special treatment. The OP's code can be made to work simply by changing three constants.

Answer (score 1):

Just start your loop at zero instead of one, and change the initializations of `{f1,f2,f3}` accordingly (left as an exercise for the reader).

The other solutions here that tell you to output zero first are basically cheating. You might as well just hard-code all the Fibonacci numbers. You won't get any marks for doing that.

Answer (score -1):

the approach I would take, is to print your base cases first, and then reset them after each iteration

```
int fPrev = 0, fCur = 1;

System.out.print(fPrev+" "+fCur);

for(int i = 2 ; i <= number ; i++ )
{
    int fNew = fPrev + fCur

    System.out.print(" "+fNew);
    fPrev = fCur;
    fCur = fNew;
}
```

Comment: If I dump my partially completed homework here, will you do it for me too? That way, I don't have to learn anything except how to copy and paste your code. (I'm not enrolled in any programming classes now, but I'll start if you're going to do it all for me.)

Comment: @KenWhite You'd be surprised what you can learn from reading someone else's code.

Comment: Yep. Except you learn much more by learning to fix what you find that doesn't work. If the poster knows enough to have written the code posted in the q, then a general guideline of what needed to change and figuring out how to apply it would be much more useful. Sometimes greed for your own rep isn't the best way to answer questions here; sometimes a little judgement can be worth much more. (See my comment to the q, which was posted before any answer here was, for an example.) But that's OK. What languages do you know best, so I'll know what to enroll in?

Comment: @KenWhite you don't necessarily learn more.  you learn different things.  If everyone learned everything about how to solve coding problems by grinding at it on their own, you wouldn't have these things called "design patterns"

Comment: But you don't learn how to actually apply design patterns to your own code until you actually start writing your own code. When you're teaching a child to do basic math, you don't say "What's 1 + 1. I'll tell you - it's 2. What's 1 + 2? I'll tell you - it's 3." You teach them, and then ask them questions and give them time to figure it out before giving the answer. I think SO should also be a teaching resource, not just a "write my code please. OK, here you go." place. Just providing code means we get more "send me the code" questions. I prefer not to encourage them.

Comment: It says class assignment but it wasn't homework. It was just practice.